# SagePay .Net Integration Kit - Error when returning NOTAVAILABLE value for 3dSecureStatus

Tags: c#, asp.net, opayo

I have implemented SagePay payment using the Form Integration. My implementation is based on the .Net integration kit supplied by SagePay which has all been good.

Recently we have enabled 3D Secure and have encountered an issue when the value of `3DSecureStatus` returns a value of `NOTAVAILABLE`.

It would seem that when the `NOTAVAILABLE` value is returned, an error is thrown within the call to the `ConvertToSagePayMessage()` method on the `SagePayIntegration` class within the assembly `SagePay.IntegrationKit.DotNet.dll`.

Specifically, this error occurs when the value is being parsed to the `ThreeDSecureStatus` enum. This enum does not have a value for `NOTAVAILABLE` to be able to parse to, hence the error.

I have put a fix in for this for the moment to get this working for now. This fix replaces the `NOTAVAILABLE` value with `NONE`, so this now parse to a valid enum value. This is done just before the call to `ConvertToSagePayMessage()`

```
cryptDecoded = cryptDecoded.Replace("3DSecureStatus=NOTAVAILABLE", "3DSecureStatus=NONE");
```

I was just wondering why the `ThreeDSecureStatus` enum does not have a value for `NOTAVAILABLE`, as `NOTAVAILABLE` is one of the values that it is expected to return, which is outlined in the Form Integration Protocol guide supplied by SagePay. And was hoping to implement a more robust fix, rather than the string replace.

Comment: I have the same issue with the 3d secure enabled, I tried your solution but doesn't work for me. do you have an idea? The error is "Requested value 'NOTAVAILABLE' was not found" in SagePay.IntegrationKit.SagePayIntegration.SetPropertyValue(Object target, String propertyName, String value)

Comment: @DevT the integration kit enumerator property is 'ThreeDSecureStatus' not '3DSecureStatus'. Try this: cryptDecoded = cryptDecoded .Replace("ThreeDSecureStatus=NOTAVAILABLE", "ThreeDSecureStatus=NONE");

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the integration kit contains a bug in that the `enum` for the `3DSecure` status is missing a value for `NOTAVAILABLE`. SagePay have even told me this:

> Unfortunately this is a known issue with the .NET kit but there is no fix as of yet.

So there are three possible ways to fix this.

1. Either modify the decoded response from the server to change the value of the `3DSecureStatus` value to `NONE` (as written in the question.)
2. Use a version of the Integration Kit that has had the fix applied. You can ask SagePay for the code (they seem perfectly willing to provide it free of charge) and add in `NOTAVAILABLE` as an enum value in the `ThreeDSecureStatus.cs` file:

   ```
   public enum ThreeDSecureStatus
   {
       NONE,
       OK,
       NOAUTH,
       CANTAUTH,
       NOTAUTHED,
       ATTEMPTONLY,
       NOTCHECKED,
       INCOMPLETE,
       MALFORMED,
       INVALID,
       ERROR,
       NOTAVAILABLE //<--- Add this
   }
   ```
3. I have already gone through the process of fixing the bug and have uploaded it to a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/WiredUK/SagePay.IntegrationKit). Feel free to take the code from there. I have also updated the project to use C#6 and as such you will need to use Visual Studio 2015 or higher to use it. If you do need to use an older version, you could start with the original files from the [first commit to the repository](https://github.com/WiredUK/SagePay.IntegrationKit/commit/56ad2d535aa10b436ce7ca2a55fe9abbaeb97a8c).

Comment: wow; thanks for all this! very helpful!