# SagePay 3D secure: Requested value 'NOTAVAILABLE' was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, opayo

I have implemented SagePay payment based on the .Net integration kit supplied by SagePay.

All works fine but when I enable the 3D Secure and choose a non-3D secure card I get this exception:

> "Requested value 'NOTAVAILABLE' was not found" |
>   Boolean TryParseEnum(System.Type, System.String, Boolean, EnumResult ByRef)

That exception occurs in the method **GetServerNotificationRequest()** on the **SagePayIntegration** class within the assembly SagePay.IntegrationKit.DotNet.dll.

**NOTE: I already tried this solution [SagePay .Net Integration Kit - Error when returning NOTAVAILABLE value for 3dSecureStatus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142334/sagepay-net-integration-kit-error-when-returning-notavailable-value-for-3dsec)
but didn't work for me.**